# How to set ItemContainerStyle only for the first level of TreeView?

Tags: wpf, treeview, wpf-controls, itemcontainerstyle

I want to change `ItemContainerStyle` only for the items of the first level. And leave the default style for deeper levels. Is is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would create a custom [`StyleSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyleselector.aspx) that can choose a different style based on whatever criteria you decide. In your case, you'd want to check to see which `ItemsControl` owned the container (as in a `TreeView`, each `TreeViewItem` is an `ItemsControl`, and owns its children).

```
public class TreeViewFirstItemStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var element = container as TreeViewItem;
        if (element != null && ItemsControl.GetItemsOwner(element) is TreeView)
            return element.FindResource("customStyle") as Style;

        return null;
    }
}
```

You would then set it on your TreeView's ItemContainerStyleSelector property.

Comment: You mean DataTemplate but I ask about ItemContainerStyle =)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Style` `Trigger`s and test items if they are first element.
This code is just an idea:

```
<Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFirst" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Color" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
```